# ImageView has an View ID but no Parameters

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, imageview

So first of all i am Aware of the fact, that there are numerous questions and answers out there about ImageViews, but i have researched this site haven't really goten to an answer. In advance i want to apologize for my amazing english skills due to me not beeing born in an english Country.

My Problem: I have an activity which is supposed to Show/Draw a given Image and i tried to realise that with a Fragment, because i want the Image to be drawn different every time i open the Fragment. Also i dont want any UserInput while the Fragment is in the foreground. A lil shorter: a Image Pops up for about a Second and vanishes again, and the User doesn't control what, when, how, and where the Images gets displayed. The Problem occured to me when i tried to get the ImageView in the Fragment in the onCreate ( also tried onResume, onActivityCreated...) and then create a Bitmap inwhich i draw my Image.

Logcat doesn't give me any Errors, the Program just dies while "creating" the Bitmap. The Problem is that somehow i get the ImageView but it has no height, no width or really anything apart from the ID.

here is the code :

the Activity which calls the Fragment:

```
package com.example.sehtestapp;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class AnswerViewer extends ActionBarActivity
{


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.answer_viewer);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        //This calls the Fragment
        ViewerFragment viewerFragment = new ViewerFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("index", 200);
        viewerFragment.setArguments(args);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.answer_layout, viewerFragment).commit();

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Then we have the Fragment itself:

```
package com.example.sehtestapp;

import java.util.Random;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ViewerFragment extends Fragment{

   int size;
   View view;
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       Bundle args = getArguments();
       size = args.getInt("index");
       /**
       * Inflate the layout for this fragment
       */
      view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewer_fragment, container, false);
      return view;
   }
   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstances){
            Random r = new Random();
            short direction = (short) r.nextInt(9);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.SehtestViewer);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(iv.getWidth(), iv.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
//this line above breakes the Programm. the imageView gets and ID but no other params.

//here is just alot of drawing to which the Programm never gets
   }
}
```

here is the viewer_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background = "#FFBB00"
android:id ="@+id/viewer_layout">
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/SehtestViewer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/abc_textfield_searchview_right_holo_dark" 
    android:contentDescription="@string/viewfield_of_sehtestring"/>
```

Thanks for all replying and reading in advance and i hope for some fast replys :D

Comment: post logcat error, i think you need change `onActivityCreated` to `onViewCreated`

Comment: sorry i didnt answer yet :D but in the Fragment LifeCycle as seen here : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html  there is no Methode called "onViewCreated" or similiar methods to be overriden

Comment: read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated%28android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle%29

Comment: first of all, the answer below fixed it :D, but to the LifeCycle Problem, as stated in the question, i have tried multiple LifeCycle Points, to try and get the Parameters. And if you read your link "onViewCreated" is immidiatly called after onCreateView, so putting the .createBitmap line in onResume, which is as far as i know the last LifeCyclePoint, before the Fragment is completly started should have fixed the issue, right? Well it didnt. I guess in onViewCreated, is the Point, from where i can first get the ImageView, but the Parameters can first be obtained AFTER onResume, seen below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views' width and height are not set until it's actually going to be rendered (so inside onCreate, you'll always will have zero width and height)

You should use a ViewTreeObserver:

```
ViewTreeObserver vtObserver = iv.getViewTreeObserver(); 
vtObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() 
{ 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() 
    { 
        iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
        int width  = iv.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = iv.getMeasuredHeight(); 
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    } 
});
```

Comment: This sounds interresting, i thought that there might be a similiar issue as described by you with the "not rendered yet" thing. Will definatly try this tommorow ASAP

Comment: Thanks alot :D works fine. Had some issues with the LifeCycle but that was because i didnt call super.onActivityCreated(). And you might fix a typo in the Bitmap Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width >>,<< height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); Anyways thanks alot

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for the type warning, already fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In **answer_viewer.xml**, add a layout as follows.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background = "#FFBB00"
android:id ="@+id/fragment_container">
```

In **AnswerViewer.java** file, in **public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)** function,
replace with this statement.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, viewerFragment).commit();
```

Move this statement

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
```

to **onActivityCreated()**

Hope this helps you.

Comment: didnt i do exactly this, apart from the    Bundle args = getArguments();    which isn't even needed in this scope yet? and my "fragment_container" ID is named "viewer_layout".

Comment: ok i dint know exactly what the issue is, if you dont see the code correctly displayed or whatever but in my XML there is a line  >android:id ="@+id/viewer_layout"< and in AnswerViewer.Java there is a line >getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.answer_layout, viewerFragment).commit();< in the onOptionsCreate Methode. and i get the Fragment to start when i dint try to get the ImageView. I actually do get an Instance of an ImageView it just has no Parameters.